# django rendering template issue

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm just built my django project but have some problem. I want to display title that is in Academy. When I run `python manage.py runserver` everything is okay but the title is not displayed. I don't know what the problem is.

**class.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
        <div style="margin-top: 200px;">
        </div>
        {% for academy in academys %}
            <h3>{{ academy.title }}</h3>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^academy/class', 'academy.views.class', name='class'),
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, Http404
from .models import Academy

def class(request):
    template = 'academy/class.html'
    try:        
        academys = Academy.objects.all()
        context = {'academy': academys}

    except Academy.DoesNotExit:
        raise Http404

    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/login/")
```

**models.py**

```
...
class Academy(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 2):

Your context dictionary key is incorrect. Instead of

```
context = {'academy': academys}
```

type

```
 context = {'academys': academys}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've passing 'academy' in your context not 'academys'

```
context={'academys ': academys}
```